# Unreal Engine 4: Adding free roam ability

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I'm trying to modify the template First Person Shooter that came with UE4 installation. I have removed the mannequin arms from the model, and currently trying to figure out a way to add free-roam ability.

Preferably, I want to toggle between free-roam and normal view on a button click. In addition to the C++ script, I would also like to know if the same thing is achievable through blueprint scripting.

Comment: And what have you tried doing?

Comment: I have tried following [this](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Gameplay/HowTo/UsingCameras/Blueprints/index.html#usingacameracomponent) guide, but it's for a static camera, I need a 'free-view' ability.

Comment: That guide does not contain any kind of code (and it only adds a camera to a scene) - you need to create a script for handling the input and modifying the camera (orientation, position, etc.)

Comment: There's also this [documentation guide](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Programming/Tutorials/PlayerCamera/2/) I came along. But, here the camera is linked to a pawn. For my use-case, I only need to move around the camera using 'WASD' keys (remaining in bound of current map).

Comment: It still sounds as if you were asking us to write code for you - which is not how SO works. You need to try doing something yourself and then you can ask for help with what you have done

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution that comes to mind is to add a second camera that isn't attached to the player, and just toggle between the two cameras (this, of course, is assuming the main problem is that you can't turn your current camera into a free cam by simply detaching it from the mannequin). If you're using blueprints, you can just use a flip flop, or if you're using C++, it may be easier to just create some boolean state (BOOL bIsFreeCam) or something.

Beyond that, it's really as simple as having an if statement to check which state your in, and fall into whichever control system (WASD moves mannequin while viewport is set to cam1, or WASD moves cam2 while viewport is set to cam2) is desired.

If you want, you can go as far as to always set cam2 to the same position as cam1 while bIsFreeCam is false (not in free cam), that way your free cam starts wherever your camera was when toggling off of mannequin control. If you're looking for the specific functions that accomplish this, those are all available in EPIC's UE4 documentation online.

Answer (score 0):

Or have two distinct pawns - one a Character for normal play, and one a Spectator for free-roam. Unless you have a different definition of free-roam. Then have your PlayerController possess and unpossess the pawn when needed.